# Dynamic pagination by counting the number of rows and a pre-defined result per page (rpp) with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I whipped up some code to count the number of rows from my database, and through a little script, display "Page : 1 2 3 4 5" etc.

Here is my code:

```
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows
$rpp = 20
$totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$rpp);
$i;

for (i=0; i<totalPages; i++){
    echo "Page: " . "<a href='index.php?page=\"$i\"rpp=20>\"$i\"</a>";
}
```

Does this look good? Do I need anything else?

EDIT 1: Added ceil() to round up. No more missing results :-)!

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. It looks like you're new to PHP, so now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to round $totalPages to the next highest integer, ie.

$totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$rpp);